# Describing a bounded set in $\Bbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $B\subset\Bbb{R^n}$ and bounded. May I claim that $B$ can be contained within a rectangle $D_{\delta}$, which is constructed by multiplying intervals of $\Bbb{R}$, with length $\delta>0$? So this rectangle would have a measure of $\delta^n$. Also, if this is true, is this then equivalent with the definition of a bounded set or a consequence of it?

Comment: What definition are you using?

Comment: That $B$ is contained within a ball of radius $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, the two are equivalent.

There is also a more "inherent" definition of bounded which says that $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ is bounded if there exists some $M > 0$ such that $\|x - y\| < M$ for all $x, y \in B$. You can show that this coincides with the ball definition (and hence, with the rectangle definition).

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent, since we can always draw a box around a ball and a ball around a box in Euclidean space.